# How to keep the application window alive even after running?

Tags: java, jar, exe, launch4j

I have created a java program. Exported it as an JAR via Eclipse and then using Launch4j I converted the jar file to an exe file with an header type of Console. The program runs successfully asks the input and also displays the output but closes immediately. Is there a way I can keep the window alive till the user presses some key or closes the window himself?

Comment: A "console application" is supposed to be run *from a console*. Do that and there should be no problem

Comment: place system.exit(0); for keypress event after completing your process I guess thats your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a prompt at the end of your code to keep it open, something like this:

```
System.out.println("Press 'Enter' key to exit.");
System.console().readLine();
```

Comment: But I am giving it to somebody else. I can't expect him to go to console and do all this. So looking for any change in program which will force it to run until explicitly told to exit.

Comment: I see. I changed my answer.